# Null/Col/Row space be a line\plane through the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

For a $4\times3$ matrix can the **nullspace**, the **column space** and **row space** all be **lines through the origin**?

For a $2\times4$ matrix can the **nullspace**, the **column space** and **row space** all be **planes through the origin**?

Lines through the origin and planes through the origin are implying that zero vector is in those dimensions?

I didn't understand the question.

Comment: If it comforts you, I also don't understand it.

Comment: yes it does comfort me, But I start wondering about why other (around 100) student didn't complain about it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, a "line through the origin" is a $1$-dimensional subspace, whereas a "plane through the origin" is a $2$-dimensional subspace.

The first question, then, is if it is possible for all of these spaces to have dimension $1$, and the second is whether it is possible for all of them to have dimension $2$.

The key here is to apply the rank-nullity theorem.  The answer to the first question is no, and the answer to the second is yes.

Answer (score 0):

> For a $4\times 3$ matrix can the nullspace, the column space and row space all be lines through the origin?

A basis for the column space can be composed of one single vector in $\mathbb R^4$, because the other $2$ vectors completing the columns of the matrix can be linearly dependent. In this case, this single vector will span a line through the origin - vector spaces always include the origin (the vectors are anchored at the origin). Given that the ranks of the column and row spaces are identical, a basis of the row space, in this scenario, consists of one vector (spanning a line through the origin) in $\mathbb R^3$.

The null space is the set of vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ that get projected to zero by the matrix, or equivalently, the set of vectors that, when dotted with each row vector in the matrix, result in zero. Geometrically this means that the vectors in the null space are orthogonal to each vector in the row space. If the row space is a vector defining a line through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$, the vectors orthogonal to this line will span a plane (not a line) through the origin:

[image]

> For a $2\times 4$ matrix can the nullspace, the column space and row space all be planes through the origin?

If two column vectors are independent, they will span a plane in $\mathbb R^2$; while the two independent vectors in the row space span a hyper-plane through the origin in $\mathbb R^4.$ The vectors orthogonal to this plane in $\mathbb R^4$ will span another hyper-plane.